# Do most people get more social security than they pay or vice versa

Tags: social-security

You pay social security your whole working life and then take it out after you retire.  Do most people pay more into social security than what they eventually take out or other way around?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to answer in regards to the US social security system. Other countries could have a different experience.

For a pension system to work, and social security is a pension system where the person pay a defined amount in to the system as does they employer, the person has to believe that they will get more money out of the system then they put into the system. The same is true of many insurance policies.

If you think that the employer portion never belonged to the worker, then the simple answer is yes the worker the average worker collects more than they put into the system.

The US Social Security Administration has a website where you can see your [account information](https://www.ssa.gov/myaccount/statement.html).

> Your Social Security Statement (Statement) is available to view online
> at anytime by opening a my Social Security account. It is useful for
> people of all ages who want to learn about their future Social
> Security benefits and current earnings history.

You could use this to see how long you would have to collect before you collect more than you contributed. Of course the farther away retirement is, the more guesses you have to make regarding future income and future contributions.

Now if you consider the portion paid by your employer to be your money. The math is a little more complex because that means you have essentially doubled your contributions, but the monthly payment you will receive remained the same. The breakeven point is pushed out.

To make this even more complex the system works by paying money for current retries out of the money being paid into he system by current workers. As long as the number of current workers is high more money flows into the system. But as the population ages that might not be true anymore. That means the system will have to dip into the trust fund which could start the strain the system. This whole discussion is very complex and can be fraught with emotion.

So do most collect more than they contribute? It depends on how you measure.

Comment: "the person has to believe that they will get more money out of the system then they put into the system. The same is true of many insurance policies." - Not really true. People pay more for insurance than they receive, because they are paying for the insurance company to absorb the risk.

Comment: Is US social security hypothecated like this? In the UK it all goes into one big pot with other taxes and then the pot gets spent on roads, hospitals, schools, social care etc. So it’s not really a meaningful question to ask.

Comment: People *usually* pay more for insurance than they receive. The purpose of insurance is to spread the cost of rare but costly events across a larger population. If you are unfortunate enough to require the full benefit of an insurance policy, you'll probably get more than you ever payed in.

Comment: @user253751 The math says that they will pay more than they will receive. But sometimes they buy insurance even when the math says not to. That is why an entire industry exists to  sell consumers extended warranties. I just checked I can pay $5.00 to protect my $13.00 computer mouse for two years.

Comment: "The breakeven pint" Is this where you go out and have a pint of beer because you've finally made it to the breakeven point?

Comment: Re "...the person has to believe that they will get more money out of the system then they put into the system."  This is incorrect WRT Social Security payments.  A person just has to believe that their employer is going to take the taxes out, regardless, or if they're self-employed, that the IRS is likely to catch the non-payment.  Social Security isn't voluntary.  Nor is it really true of any insurance policy. For instance, I have home insurance, even though I don't really expect that my house will burn down :-)

Answer (score 2):

The average American who turned 65 used to receive more benefits than he/she paid into the system.  That changed 10-15 years ago.

This is due to several factors.

- The retirement age is increasing for younger age groups (it's now 67 for those born after 1959)
- People are retiring at a later age

Within the average there are different stats.  Single men are hit harder (lower life expectancy) whereas a couple with a single breadwinner nets more benefits (two recipients, one income).

Comment: Single breadwinner = 1 1/2 recipients, not 2 recipients.  You get half of your spouse's benefits if they are still alive.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel - There's no such thing as half a person, aka recipient.  However, one person may receive half the benefit.  Regardless, two recipients receiving benefits is the winner because in aggregate, they're likely to have paid less and will receive more.

Comment: Getting half benefits is what I meant by half a recipient.

Answer (score 1):

(Note that this applies to the US Social Security system.  Other countries probably differ in many ways.)

Logically, you would expect to get more out, on average.  But the answer is complicated, since it depends on just how you define "more", because you're not using constant dollars.

Say for instance you retired this year at age 66.  You probably started working in 1975, when you 20.  So you started paying in to Social Security in 1975 dollars, which were worth about 5 times as much as today's dollars: https://www.in2013dollars.com/us/inflation/1975  Now the SS benefit calculation has an inflation index built in, so you will get more, measured in absolute dollars.  But maybe not in purchasing power :-(  That depends on how well the SS index corresponds to real inflation.

Another point is that the SS system has historically collected more in taxes than it has paid out in benefits.  That means there has been a large pile of money, the Social Security Trust Fund, that is invested in US T-bills.  These pay interest (even if not much over inflation), thus you would expect to receive some of that interest as part of your retirement benefit.

Beyond that, there are a host of complicating factors.  It comes down to just who you calculate that average person to be.

Benefit amounts are not a simple percentage of contributions.  The formula used to calculate the amount is fairly heavily weighted towards lower income earners. See the SS web site for the official explanation https://www.ssa.gov/oact/cola/Benefits.html or a more accessible one here: https://www.fool.com/retirement/whats-the-social-security-benefit-formula.aspx  All else aside, lower earners can expect more, high earners less.

Then there are spousal benefits.  A person who has never paid in, or who has paid in very little, can collect a benefit based on their spouse's (or in some cases former spouses) earnings.

You also need to ask when that "average person" is doing the expecting?  About 12% of today's 20-somethings will die before reaching full retirement age.  They get no benefits (though there are survivor benefits &c), so the average person at retirement age can expect to benefit from their uncollected contributions.